# make a button work in different ways in odd and even clicks

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I know my question might have been asked a milion times but I am really stuck even after 4 hours of research; what I would like to do is geting an onclick function over an image to work differenly in odd and even clicks:

```
<div class= "random button" onclick = "myFunction()"> 
  <img class="cool image"> 
</div> 
<div class = "very cool content"> 
  <p>lorem</p>
</div>

function myFunction () {
 var x = 0;
 if (x - math.floor(x) = 0) {
   document.getElementByClass("very cool content").style.display = "grid";
   var x = x + 0.5;
 } else {
   document.getElementByClass("very cool content").style.display = "none";
   var x = x + 0.5;
 }
```

I know this question is very stupid but I am absolutely incompetent in javascript and I wasn't able to implement any of the answers I founded online so please help me.

Comment: Comparisons in Javascript are made with double equal `==`. Single equal `=` is for assignement. In Console (F12) you are getting a "Syntax error" where it says exactly where's the problem. I recommend a lot working with Console open.

Comment: You are also setting x to zero every time the method executes.   Easiest way to do what you're trying to do is to use a class that applies the display of grid to the element and just toggle it on each function execution

Comment: your code have the following problems: getElementByClass is not a standard function. getElementsByClass returns an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Js does not save the value of x between two clicks that cannot work. But you can define the two stats and alternate like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick = "myFunction()" value="Click me!">  
<div class="content"> 
  <p>lorem</p>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction () {
    let even = 'grid';
    let odd = 'none';
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("content")

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
        element.style.display === even ? element.style.display = odd : element.style.display = even
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I copied the code from the question without thinking. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Man you solved my problem now it works and I would add that I wrote getElementsByClassName just for the sake of semplicity in my code I switched to getElemntById and it works perfectly thanks man!!

Comment: Finally got it right :D 
Where is my head today *sigh*. Thanks @Taplar for your notice

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to base your visibility off of a class.  And then your logic can simply toggle that class every click.

```js
function myFunction () {
  document.querySelector('.very.cool.content').classList.toggle('visible');
}
```

```css
.very.cool.content:not(.visible) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class= "random button" onclick = "myFunction()"> 
  <img class="cool image" alt="Cool Image"> 
</div> 
<div class = "very cool content"> 
  <p>lorem</p>
</div>
```